# Trying to get Uppercase lowercase jquery code to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Code:

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.upperlower', function() {
  var z = document.getElementById("text").value;
  var x = z.toLowerCase();
  x = x.replace(/\b./g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
  alert(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control upperlower" placeholder="Last Name, First Name">
```

and I am missing why the jQuery does not execute to change the `input` case.

- input : JOHN DOE expected output : John Doe

Can anyone cast me a string?

Comment: You search for an element with id `text`, but you have none.

Comment: `z=document.getElementById("text").value;` should be `z=document.querySelector(".form-control").value;`

Comment: use `var z= $('input[type="text"]').value;`

Comment: Better use `var z = this.value;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You search for an element with `id=text`, but you don't have that. It is better to use `this` which is provided by jQuery to your callback function:

```js
$(document).on('blur','.upperlower',function(){
    var z=this.value;
    var x=z.toLowerCase();
    x=x.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
    alert(x);   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control upperlower" placeholder="Last Name, First Name">
```

If you want to have this happen also when the form submits, then also capture that submit event. In below snipped no alert is given, but the replacement is done on the input value. I have commented out the action on the blur event, so it is clear that the submit button also performs that action:

```js
// create a named function, so both event handlers can use the same code:
function upperLower(){
    this.value = this.value.toLowerCase()
         .replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
}

// Uncomment this line if you want the action to happen on blur as well 
//$(document).on('blur','.upperlower', upperLower);

$('form').on('submit', function() {
    $('.upperlower').each(upperLower);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
<input type="text" class="form-control upperlower" placeholder="Last Name, First Name" value="john DOE">
<input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: I tried this, and its part of a form submit modal, which upon submit is still not running the code?  It just shows an alert with the correct value

Comment: The code you provided only had a handler for the blur event, not for the submit event. I updated my answer yesterday with a second code example that implements the submit event handler. Does this reply to your needs?

Comment: I am sorry, I did not explain.  This code is for whatever reason, no even happening on blur(which I believe should happen when I tab between form fields)The only thing it IS doing, is showing the alert message, but I want it to REPLACE the users input, not only alert what the correct input should be

Comment: Did you check my second snippet, it replaces the input. I disabled the action on the blur event in that snippet for demonstration purposes, but my answer specified that you could uncomment that line. I also explained at the top of my answer why your code was not working.

Answer (score 1):

you always can use `this` for your callback function in jQuery.

P.S. - You don't have `id="text"` in your input.

```js
$(document).on('blur', '.upperlower', function() {
  var z = this.value;
  var x = z.toLowerCase();
  x = x.replace(/\b./g, function(m) {
    return m.toUpperCase();
  });
  console.log(x);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control upperlower" placeholder="Last Name, First Name">
```

Answer (score 0):

Stick to jquery :)

```
$(document).on('blur','.upperlower',function(){
            var z=$("#text").val();
            var x=z.toLowerCase();
            x=x.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
            alert(x);   
});
```

Changed the `var z=document.getElementById("text").value;` to `var z=$("#text").value();`

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/z8EWy6ZzlPLjdGoFrDGX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you need. Hope it helps :)

```js
$(document).on('blur','.upperlower',function(){
            var z= $(this).val();
            var x= z.toLowerCase();
            x=x.replace(/\b./g, function(m){ return m.toUpperCase(); });
            alert(x);   
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id = "myID" class="form-control upperlower" placeholder="Last Name, First Name">
```

Comment: `$('input[type="text"]').val();` won't do the right thing if you have multiple text inputs.

Comment: @Barmar yup you are right and that case we can just target the input field by its id. I just updated my answer. Thanks for that input mate :)

Comment: The other answers that use `this` are better. Your code will use the input in this specific field even when the user blurs in a different field.

Comment: @Barmar did you see my updated code? I'm not using $('input[type="text"]').val(); anymore

Comment: No, you're using `$("#myID").val()` instead of `$(this).val()`.

Comment: Didn't you notice that the event handler is attached to all inputs with the `.upperlower` class, not just this one?

Comment: @Barmar I didn't see it, but yeah code has been updated again. Thanks!